# Terminology to measure the ratio of the maximum value to the minimum value of a real-valued function?

Tags: terminology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Let $f_{\mathrm{max}}=\max_{x\in \mathbb R} f(x)$ and $f_{\mathrm{min}}=\min_{x\in \mathbb R} f(x)$.
Define $r$ as the ratio of $f_{\mathrm{max}}$  to $f_{\mathrm{min}}$.

Intuitively, $r$ measures the "turbulence" of $f$.
Is there a specific terminology for $r$?

Comment: if you want to measure spread, would not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation be a better measure ?

Comment: @MBobrik I have to use the exact definition of $r$ in my work, so I was wondering whether this ratio has been named.